# How to make the org-mode exported table aligned in GMail?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I have a table maintained by org-mode, and I would like to copy/paste it to an email.

So this is what I was trying to do:

1. export to the plain text
2. copy/paste to the gmail

However, it just cannot aligned correctly among different columns.. This is something like this:

[image]

Could anyone help me on this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Best guess: `org-mode` assumes a monospaced font when it exports, but you're using a non-monospaced font in your email program, which throws off the alignment.

Comment: You could export the table to Markdown and use [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/) in your email.

Comment: @KaraWoo, great! This is what I am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @computereasy glad to hear it, I'll go ahead and make this an answer then

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can export the table to Markdown and use [Markdown Here](http://markdown-here.com/) to format the table in your email.

`M-x org-md-export-as-markdown` will export your document as Markdown, but the tables will be exported as HTML. This may be fine for your purposes, but if not you can install [ox-pandoc](https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc) and export your org-mode document with `M-x org-pandoc-export-as-markdown_github`.

This will convert an org table:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
|----------+----------|
| a        |        1 |
| b        |        2 |
| c        |        3 |
```

To a Markdown table:

```
| Column 1 | Column 2 |
|----------|----------|
| a        | 1        |
| b        | 2        |
| c        | 3        |
```

Paste this table into your email and use Markdown Here (keyboard shortcut: Ctrl-Alt-m) to format it. It should then look like this:

[image: Rendered table]

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a solution for me with Chrome, new gmail, OSX. This even with restarting. https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/issues/504